# Is it possible to export a model built in R for use in SAS?

Tags: r, sas

I built a model in R that I now need to use in SAS. I'm aware of R packages like haven that can write SAS-readable data files, but I can't find anything that can convert a model from R to SAS. Is this possible or am I wasting my time?

Comment: What do you call a model ? A function, coefficients, etc.

Comment: Depends on too many things to answer. What type of model? What type of SAS installation do you have? Does that particular R package generate a PMML file? It's not perfect, but PMML is considered a decent method to implement models from one system into another.

Comment: SAS does integrate with R. It may be easier to run the model through R and send the output to SAS for additional processing, if that's what you are looking to do. PROC IML makes this easier, but you can call it through SAS through other means.